# SQL Where between word value ranges (eg., "low" to "high")

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a field in my database that has 5 possible values: fair, good, very good, ideal, siganture ideal

I have a coldfusion form that has 2 drop-downs each with all the values.  What I am looking to do is be able to have the user select a range.  For example dropdown1 = Fair dropdown2 = Very Good. So this would somehow generate the SQL WHERE statement:

grade IN ('fair', 'good', 'very good')

Can you think of a smart way to program this given that the values have to be this way. I think maybe if I put them in an array and then looped through it or something.  I'm a little stumped on this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your DB design is wrong. :-) It should be numeric values (eg., "fair" = 0, "signature ideal" = 4), and then your query is simply a `BETWEEN` statement based on the selected item's index. Also, you should have the user select only the low value, and then display only the higher values in the second combobox (dropdown list) for them to choose - this simplifies making sure the conditions aren't reversed (eg., low = "ideal", high = "fair").

Comment: And, under almost any circumstance, it's better in the long run to address and repair the poor design than it is to code around bad design, thereby taking you even further down the wrong road.

Comment: I know the DB design thing is wrong, but its the way it is, because items are imported from a spreadsheet that way.  Thats why im here trying to come up with a workaround for an obvious but necessary flaw.

Comment: I agree the db should maintain a numeric "ranking" of the ratings. However if you can't change the db I guess you're left with with an array based approach where you can order the array and have the position in the array determine the relative ranking....

Comment: @Mark, the DB design might be stuck and there might be a good reason.  However,  the fact that you're importing the data from a spreadsheet is not an example of one.

Comment: ISTM that fixing the import process would be much more efficient (once while importing) than fighting every time you want to retrieve data matching a criteria. With that being said, I'd create an array, and use the index of the items in the dropdown to populate dynamic SQL (since you can't use parameters in an `IN` clause). This still seems like a hackish workaround instead of solving the actual problem, though. (OK, I'll stop now. <g>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others mentioned, redesigning is ultimately the better course of action, both in terms of efficiency and data integrity. However, if you *absolutely* cannot change the structure, a possible workaround is to create a lookup table of the allowable grade descriptions, along with a numeric rating value for each one:

```
 GradeID | GradeText        | Rating
 1       | Fair             | 0
 2       | Good             | 1
 3       | Very Good        | 2
 4       | Ideal            | 3
 5       | Signature Ideal  | 4
```

Then populate your select list from a query on the lookup table. Be sure to `ORDER BY Rating ASC` and use the rating number as the list value. Then on your action page, use the selected values to filter by range. (Obviously validate the selected range is valid as well)

```
  SELECT  t.ColumnName1, t.ColumnName2
  FROM    SomeTable t INNER JOIN YourLookupTable lt ON lt.Grade = t.GradeText
  WHERE   lt.Rating BETWEEN <cfqueryparam value="#form.dropdown1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
          AND <cfqueryparam value="#form.dropdown2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
```

Again, I would recommend restructuring instead. However, the above should work if that is really not an option.

Comment: Wow this looks excellent, I won't have a chance to try it out for a bit but will let you know if it works out. Thanks so much.

Comment: Tried it out tonight - works like a dream. Thanks for your help.